How to get useragent variables of Ace editor
https://ace.c9.io/api/modules/src_lib_useragent.html
I need useragent.isMac variable for display in markup hot keys for the mac(Cmd) user and for win(ctrl). How to get useragent variables in ace_builds?
I've tried to search by logging to console the imported ace object, but no results
import * as ace from "ace-builds/src-noconflict/ace"


with ace-builds you can do
ace.require("ace/lib/useragent")

